# Propositional Logic - Semantics

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, solution-verification

**Is it the case that:** $\models(p_{2}\to p_{0}) \to p_{0}$?

I took the liberty to rewrite the given expression into Boolean algebra
$$(p_{2}\to p_{0}) \to p_{0} \approx (p_{2} \land \neg p_{0}) \lor p_{0}$$
which can also be written as $(p_{2} \lor p_{0}) \land (\neg p_{0} \lor p_{0})$. Now, from this outset it seems to me that $\not \models (p_{2}\to p_{0}) \to p_{0}$ because it is not a tautology - i.e. $[[(p_{2}\to p_{0}) \to p_{0}]]_{v} \neq1$ for all valuations $v$. Is this a valid answer (meaning is it correct)? And, how can I construct a more formal reasoning (semantic proof/counterexample) of my sketch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saying it is not a tautology is *almost* sufficient. We need to *show* it is not a tautology. One mechanical way to do this is to draw up a complete truth table, and show that for some assignment of truth values to $p_0$, $p_2$ we get the result "False."

More directly, let us see how $(p_2\longrightarrow p_0)\longrightarrow p_0$ could be false: If $p_0$ is false and $p_2\longrightarrow p_0$ is true. That can be arranged: Make $p_0$ false and $p_2$ false.

Comment: Thanks for you quick reply! You are a champ! I will make sure to accept your answer once it is possible (in six minutes). That is what I will do, construct a truth table. Any other methods, if that is possible, would be very much appreciated.

Comment: @user94284 As to other methods:  if it _were_ a tautology, then you could write a proof of it (appealing to the soundness of propositional calculus).  If it's negation _were_ a tautology, then you could prove its negation, $\lnot\phi$, and then, by the completeness of the propositional calculus, have shown that $\phi$ must be false.

Comment: I cannot think of a substantially different kind of idea, since in essence we are trying to show non-provability. One can first do a formal manipulation, finding an equivalent expression. For example, we can use your calculation, getting $(p_{2} \land \neg p_{0}) \lor p_{0}$, then $(p_2\lor \lnot p_0)\land (p_0\lor \lnot p_0)$. The part $p_0\lor \lnot p_0$ is automatically true, so we need $p_2\lor \lnot p_0$ to be true. It is easy to see how to falsify $p_2\lor \lnot p_0$. The idea is quite general, to look for a counterexample we put the expression in **conjunctive normal form** (CNF) (more)

Comment: (more) In our case, the calculation is more complicated than what we used, but not much more complicated. One can think of it as a "Boolean algebra" version of truth tables. The CNF, and its companion the DNF (disjunctive normal form) are important, in looking at the *satisfiability* problem.